# Mongoose: Cannot read property 'where' of undefined, _id

Tags: mongoose, unique, model-validation, mongoose-models

I've got that model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

var EquipmentSchema = new Schema({
    model: { type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    comments: { type: String },
    market: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Market', required: true },
    category: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category', required: true },
    make: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Make', required: true },
    rv: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Rv'}],
});

EquipmentSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Equipments', EquipmentSchema);
```

This function to save new items:

```
const Equipments = require('./_models/equipment.model');

var equipmentSaver = function(equipment) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(equipment);
    const equipmentToSave = new Equipments({
      _id: equipment.type.model._id,
      market: equipment.type.market._id,
      category: equipment.type.category._id,
      make: equipment.type.make._id,
      model: equipment.type.model.name,
      price: equipment.economicDetails.price,
      comments: equipment.economicDetails.comments,
    });
    equipmentToSave.save()
      .then(result => resolve(result))
      .catch(error => reject(error))
   });
}

module.exports = equipmentSaver;
```

And I'm getting that JSON from the front:

```
{
  type: {
    market: {
      _id: '5eb1a63926849bed71155592',
      name: 'Healthcare',
      icon: 'local_hospital'
    },
    category: {
      _id: '5eb19f080141dbe4b9aebc9a',
      name: 'Diagnostico por la imagen',
      market: '5eb1a63926849bed71155592'
    },
    make: {
      _id: '5ebd3e107002040000e70e53',
      name: 'GE',
      category: '5eb19f080141dbe4b9aebc9a'
    },
    model: {
      _id: '5ebd3e167002040000e70e54',
      name: 'Voluson S8',
      make: '5ebd3e107002040000e70e53'
    }
  },
  economicDetails: {
    comments: 'Description',
    price: 45000,
    used: false
  }
}
```

All the `_ids` are created by the front and I get **these 2 errors**: 
1.

```
Error [ValidationError]: Equipments validation failed: _id: Cannot read property 'where' of undefined, model: Cannot read property 'where' of undefined
    at ValidationError.inspect
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
      message: "Cannot read property 'where' of undefined",
      name: 'ValidatorError',
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'unique',
      path: '_id',
      value: 5ebd3e167002040000e70e54,
      reason: TypeError: Cannot read property 'where' of undefined
```

2.

```
MongooseError [ValidatorError]: Cannot read property 'where' of undefined
        at new ValidatorError
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
      message: "Cannot read property 'where' of undefined",
      name: 'ValidatorError',
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'unique',
      path: 'model',
      value: 'Voluson S8',
      reason: TypeError: Cannot read property 'where' of undefined
```

I have no idea why. I feel this has something to do with the "unique" character of both these fields but I'm not sure why it throws this error...

EDIT: I've found the origin of the error. When I deleted the `EquipmentSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);` from my model, it saves correctly again... 
I've created an issue on [mongoose-unique-validator's github](https://github.com/blakehaswell/mongoose-unique-validator/issues/118) but if anyone here has had the same problem or even has a solution that'd be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the problem comes from the name of one of your fields : 
the `model` field in the `EquipmentSchema`

```
var EquipmentSchema = new Schema({
    //this throws Cannot read property 'where' of undefined
    model: { type: String, required: true, unique: true} 
    ...
})
```

When you rename this field to something else or remove it, the plugin works just fine.
Still, it's the `mongoose-unique-validator` plugin issue because `model` is not
in the [list of reserved document keys](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema.reserved)
of mongoose.

By looking in [this section of the plugin code](https://github.com/blakehaswell/mongoose-unique-validator/blob/2.0.3/index.js#L92-L106)
(the latest release), you can see there are `if ... else if ...` conditions to find
the `model`, and defining a field named `model` as you did, makes all the conditions fail and leaves the `model` variable undefined which finally throws the error.

Comment: Hey mousto090! Amazing! I’ll update the info on their repo citing you, see if they can precise / fix this!